# new Date() not returning region

Tags: javascript, moment-timezone

Normally `new Date()` returns the time, time-zone and region, like `Thu Sep 02 2021 15:04:30 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)`, but for some reason two of my colleague's computer isn't returning the region, and only shows something like `Thu Sep 02 2021 15:04:30 GMT+0800 (GMT+8)`.

I originally discovered this because when we use moment-timezone's `moment.tz.guess()`, it returns `Etc/GMT-8` instead of `Aisa/Taipei`, and thought it might have something to do with the browser not being able to get the user's location, as mentioned in [moment.js' official docs](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/).

We're sure it's not a browser issue though, since we've tested it on Edge, Chrome and Firefox.

Any ideas on why this happens?

Comment: Is there a region set in the tz settings of the OS?

Comment: JavaScript gets the date, time and timezone information from the underlying OS. Check their computers have the correct timezone info set up in the system settings.

Comment: @derpirscher yes, I've checked that and it's set to Taiwan

Comment: Are they using different versions of Windows?

Comment: @phuzi Nope, both of them are using Windows 10

Comment: Hmm, [timeanddate.com shows Taipei observing China Standard Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/taiwan/taipei)

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your error. `new Date().toString()` returns region as expected. I vote to close this question because not reproducible.

Comment: @phuzi Yeah we're on the same timezone, it's just on our website we'd like to show the user where they are, so instead of showing GMT+8 we'd like to show Aisa/Taipei, or if they're in China something like Aisia/Shanghai

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito Well imagine my frustration because it only happens on my colleague's computers hahaha

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito I think closing because not reproducible is not appropriate for this question. I would reserve that for a code specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok we tested it out, and it *IS* an issue with the OS's settings.

So the computers' regions are both initially set to Taiwan, and what we did was we tried setting it to elsewhere, then setting it back again. And...for some reason that did the trick.

Weird, but I guess strange things just happens on Windows.

But thanks for all the replies! Hopefully this can help another confused user in the future...